# RDS can't create a database

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to create an SQL Server database under the free tier options in AWS.

After going through the standard options - database name, password, public/private access, etc.. I press the create database button. I get the following screen.

[image]

But the database never gets created. I saw multiple tutorials.. but I haven't seen a similar problem. Does anyone have a clue what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did the role get created? also, you can try CLI command. usually you get better errors with CLI...

Comment: @Felix no, the create database button just keeps loading. I did manage to create a MySQL database though. So looks like the issue is with the MS SQL license. Unfortunately, there is no clear error message.

Comment: Sounds like a browser UI issue. Can you try a different browser? It would _not_ be related to licensing.